# Why I have error in console according to reCAPTCHA

Tags: javascript, angular, recaptcha, console.log

I load recaptcha like this:

`<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=vcRecaptchaApiLoaded&render=explicit" async defer></script>`

and I have angular-recaptcha in my node modules, and I load it in path.js           `'node_modules/angular-recaptcha/release/angular-recaptcha.js'`,

and I have problem in console: 
`reCAPTCHA couldn't find user-provided function: vcRecaptchaApiLoaded`

I tried change order of load this files but it doesn't work. My Captcha works fine, but I have ugly info in my console.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the script src: onload=vcRecaptchaApiLoaded

You can either provide this function or remove the part from src.

Comment: ok, you're right, when I remove it from src, it doesn't show error in console, but it's tricky because I think that someone add it for some reason here, so I'm afraid, that when I remove it,something will break it. I see that vcRecaptchaApiLoaded is function from angular-recaptcha https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-recaptcha/4.2.0/angular-recaptcha.min.js, so I'm afraid that maybe is necessary in some case.